# add XML node with formatting

Tags: c#, xml, formatting

I am adding a node to the XML file, but I need it to be properly formatted. Could you assist with it?

```
        String newFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);

        //file name
        string filename = @"palette.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filename);

        //create node and add value
        XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "item", null);

        //create title node
        XmlNode nodeTitle = doc.CreateElement("name");
        //add value for it
        nodeTitle.InnerText = @"<![CDATA["+newFile+"]]>";

        //create Url node
        XmlNode nodeUrl = doc.CreateElement("imgfile");
        nodeUrl.InnerText = newFile;

        //add to parent node
        node.AppendChild(nodeTitle);
        node.AppendChild(nodeUrl);

        //add to elements collection
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);

        //save back
        doc.Save(filename);
```

The XML should be looking like that:

```
  <item>
  <name><![CDATA[panda.gif]]></name>
  <imgfile>panda.gif</imgfile>
  </item>
```

but it look like that:

```
  <item>
  <name>&lt;![CDATA[panda.gif]]&gt;</name>
  <imgfile>panda.gif</imgfile>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method you can use to wrap cdata it is.

```
XMLNode.AppendChild( XMLDocument.CreateCDataSection( newFile ) );
```

It XMLDocument.CreateCDataSection returns XmlCDataSection object which you can append to your node and it will wrap your file in CDATA.

Check this out for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx

Comment: Could you please give a better explanation?

Comment: No worries...Ok, the way that you are doing it in your code is by trying to put CDATA directly into the inner text.  That is why it is parsing incorrectly.  What the line I gave you above does is use the XMLDocument class to call a method called CreateCDataSection to wrap your string in CDATA.

Answer (score 0):

CDATA is considered a node, not an inner text

```
<item>
  <name>
    <![CDATA[panda.gif]]>
  </name>

  <imgfile>panda.gif</imgfile>
</item>
```

So:

```
XmlElement nodeTitle = document.CreateElement("name");
XmlCDataSection CDATA = document.CreateCDataSection("panda.gif");
nodeTitle.AppendChild(CDATA);
node.AppendChild(nodeTitle);
```